# Громоздкий код. Подскажите, как я могу исправить эту ситуацию

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Программа работает. При проверке программа выдаёт уравнение изображений согласно примеру из аргументов 1 и 2. В итоге мы показываем пласт уравнений согласно последней линии

```
argument1 = [[1, 1, 1],
             [1, 0, 0]]

argument2 = [[0, 0, 0],
             [1, 1, 1]]

template = [argument1, argument2]

n = 1

for data in template:
    size = len(data[0])
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            for delta in range(1, size - (i + j)):
                for m in range(len(data)):
                    print('Изображение номер - ', m + 1, sep="")
                    for func in range(len(data)):
                        print(f'{int(func == m)} = R{func + 1} = {data[m][i]} * A1({func + 1}) + {data[m][i + j + delta]} * A2({func + 1})')
```

Comment: вы бы 1) вопрос в теле письме, а не в заголовке писали бы 2) уточнили бы задачу

Comment: Укажите логику. Или что за задача решается? На вскидку можно сократить манипуляции с итерациями, поскольку нет if и не изменяются первоначальные списки. То есть использовать распаковку например `i, j = data`, манипуляции такие, как сложения через map => `sums = map(sum, zip(i,j))` и т.д. Можно заменить list на tuple, но это уже от задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы просто сделать код менее громоздким, то можно просто несколько циклов обернуть в не громоздкие функции (старый добрый Роберт Мартин)

```
def main():
    argument1 = [[1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0]]
    argument2 = [[0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1]]
    template = [argument1, argument2]

    n = 1
    for data in template:
        print_data(data)


def print_data(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            print_images_foreach_delta(data, i, j)


def print_images_foreach_delta(data, i, j):
    size = len(data[0])
    for delta in range(1, size - (i + j)):
        for image_index in range(len(data)):
            print_image(data, image_index, i, j, delta)


def print_image(data, image_index, i, j, delta):
    print('Изображение номер - ', image_index + 1, sep="")
    for func in range(len(data)):
        print(f'{int(func == image_index)} = R{func + 1} = {data[image_index][i]} * A1({func + 1}) + {data[image_index][i + j + delta]} * A2({func + 1})')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Если бы я знал, что именно должна делать программа, возможно, я дал бы именам функций и переменным более подходящие названия, да и в принципе написал бы эффективнее.

Comment: Благодарю. Это то, что нужно, но честно говоря я новичок, а задание пришлось делать практически вслепую, как котёнку. Такие нынче задачки появляются, без конкретики. Теперь буду знать, что и так можно писать код, спасибо

Comment: @ERID-_-, рад помочь!